# Saving location data to Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have looked around and found that its not suitable to store an array to core data but i have many objects that contain 
 - an array of location data
 - an array of comments
 - an array of images (i was thinking of saving the images file names and saving the image data to the documents directory)

I read that you can save the contents of an array to a string and save that to core data. i am assuming using this "componentsJoinedByString:"

So my question is what is the best approach in saving the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store an array in core data, you define an entity which will represent one object in your array (e.g. for a location it would have two float attributes for latitude and longitude, perhaps). You then create a new instance of the entity for each location.

If you want one core data entity to have multiple items as a property then you create a to-many relationship from entity a to multiple entity b's. This is implemented as a set rather than an array, though.